# Husband refusing to have children due to fear of poverty

Tags: children

Simple and short

Happily married 3 years alhamdulillah but my husband has been refusing to try for children because we don’t have our own place yet and we live with family. He works a job and has a normal income but still thinks the thought of trying for children is stressful and a big responsibility.

Me myself as the wife I am personally ready to have children and I believe Allah swt will help/provide and give me a way. I also believe that us as a couple trying for children does not guarantee that a child will be born straight away/ or this year or for any time until Allah swt himself wills.

Am I wrong?